# Как добавить арифметический знак в переменную?

Tags: javascript, математика, арифметика

Писал вот такой вот калькулятор. Однако столкнулся с проблемой, что нельзя загнать арифметический знак в переменную, потому что арифметический знак становится строковым, а если арифметический знак попытаться перевести в численный функцией, то выдает ошибку. Как быть?

Хотелось сделать что-то вроде массива и чтобы знак подставлялся в зависимости от условия, типа:

```
let devide = parseInt(/)
res.innerHTML = parseInt(val1.value) +devide+ parseInt(val2.value);
```

Но так не работает, поэтому сделать смог калькулятор только так:

```
    // Получаем значение из полей input
let val1 = document.querySelector('input[name=val1]')
let val2 = document.querySelector('input[name=val2]')
let btn = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=submit]')
let res = document.querySelector('.res')

// Обходим массив через цикл и если условие соотвествует, то подставляем нужный знак
for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].onclick = function () {
        if (btn[i].value === '-') {
            res.innerHTML = parseInt(val1.value) - parseInt(val2.value);
            this.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
        }
        else if (btn[i].value === '+') {
            res.innerHTML = parseInt(val1.value) + parseInt(val2.value);
            this.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
        }
        else if (btn[i].value === '/') {
            res.innerHTML = parseInt(val1.value) / parseInt(val2.value);
            this.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
        }
        else if (btn[i].value === '*') {
            res.innerHTML = parseInt(val1.value) * parseInt(val2.value);
            this.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
        }
        else {
            console.log('error');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: что мешает хранить арифметический знак в отдельной строке? Так будет легче, а именно просто бросил этот ар-знак в switch а там по веткам свое действие

Comment: Что-то больно хитрое вы делаете. Можно посмотреть на внешний вид калькулятора?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте воспользоваться такой конструкцией

```js
const functions = {
    '+': (a, b) => a + b,
    '-': (a, b) => a - b,
    '*': (a, b) => a * b,
    '/': (a, b) => a / b
};
const sign = '+';
const result = functions[sign](3, 5);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: а можете пояснить, что происходит? я такие массивы еще не изучал!

Comment: functions - это объект, у которого ключи это арифметические знаки +, -, *, /, а значения - стрелочные функции с соответствующими арифметическими операциями. Такой объект - это альтернатива конструкции switch-case.

Comment: круто. спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать eval:

```
var a = 1,
    b = 2,
    sign = "+";

var result = eval(a + sign + b);

console.log(result);
```

Но я бы просто код аккуратнее оформил:

```
for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {

    btn[i].onclick = function () {

        let val1 = +val1.value,
            val2 = +val2.value,
            result;

        switch (btn[i].value) {
            case '-':
                result = val1 - val2;
                break;
            case '+':
                result = val1 + val2;
                break;
            case '/':
                result = val1 / val2;
                break;
            case '*':
                result = val1 * val2;
                break;
        }

        res.innerHTML = result;

        this.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

    }

}
```